# How to export a list of the loaded libraries from windows dump file (procdump)

Tags: .net, windbg, crash-dumps, procdump

I'm looking at a *.dmp file in Visual Studio 2019 - it shows a list of the load system DLLs, filename, version, folder etc.

I want to copy this information to paste into Excel, but I can't copy it from Visual Studio.

Anyone know if I can export this to a text file from the dump file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinDbg has been covered in another answer already, so I'll refer to Visual Studio below.

First step is to load the DMP file into VS.

[image]

This initial screen also displays a list of loaded modules, but that one does not allow copying from. Instead, click Debug with Native Only on the right hand side (or one of the other options available when debugging managed or mixed mode apps), and wait for the symbols to load.

Then use the menu to open the Debug / Windows / Modules window.

[image]

This is a regular list, where you can select lines (including all lines) and Ctrl-C copy them as text.

Alternatively, open the View / Other Windows / Command Window from the menu, and enter the `debug.listModules` command.

[image]

This one is a regular text box where, again, you can select and Ctrl-C copy as needed.

Answer (score 1):

are you talking about this data like paste below ?

```
00120000 00148000   cdb        (deferred)             
    Image path: cdb.exe
    Image name: cdb.exe
    Image was built with /Brepro flag.
    Timestamp:        0324D46E (This is a reproducible build file hash, not a timestamp)
    CheckSum:         00025C20
    ImageSize:        00028000
    File version:     10.0.18362.1
    Product version:  10.0.18362.1
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        1.0 App
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    Information from resource tables:
        CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
        ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
        InternalName:     CDB.Exe
        OriginalFilename: CDB.Exe
        ProductVersion:   10.0.18362.1
        FileVersion:      10.0.18362.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
        FileDescription:  Symbolic Debugger for Windows
        LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

this is produced by lmv command in windbg (i dont know what it's equivalent maybe in vs

since you tagged windbg i will give you a short demo of gathering this info into a text file

```
D:\>cdb -logo cdbmods.txt -c "lmv;q" -z cdb.dmp
```

output that you can copy paste ,transpose , etc

```
D:\>dir /b *cdb*
cdb.dmp
cdbmods.txt

D:\>wc -l cdbmods.txt
894 cdbmods.txt


D:\>sed -n 44,48p cdbmods.txt
00360000 00388000   cdb        (deferred)
    Image path: cdb.exe
    Image name: cdb.exe
    Image was built with /Brepro flag.
    Timestamp:        0324D46E (This is a reproducible build file hash, not a timestamp)

D:\>
```